# Formatting a float number inside a Mutable string

Tags: iphone, nsmutablestring

I have a couple of floats and they all are stored in a mutable string. But while displaying them it's showing 2011.00000 inspite of 2011 so i want it to format it.
Any suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString* str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f", float_number];
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you just put them into floats and then use a stringWithFormat(@"%f4.0", ?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
NSString* sa = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%0.0f", 22323.4342];
```